# node.js command line scripts for configuration an application

Tags: javascript, node.js

file: /config/index.js;

```
var config = {
    local: {
        mode: 'local',
        port: 3000
    },
    staging: {
        mode: 'staging',
        port: 4000
    },
    production: {
        mode: 'production',
        port: 5000
    }
}
   module.exports = function(mode) {
        return config[mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'] || config.local;
    }
```

file: app.js;

```
...
var config = require('./config')();
...
http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + config.port);
});
```

what is the meaning of `config[mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'] || config.local;` .

what I know ;
1) `||` mean is "or".
2) when we enter on terminal  `node app.js staging`, `process.argv[2]` gets 2.argument from NODE.JS command line so it is "staging".

please, someone can explain these codes snippets ?

Comment: question is very useful , why gave -1 point just for two basic grammer issue ? >.<

Comment: You've answered your own question. `||` means `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part is defining the config object. Then it exports that object.

When you call this module from another file/code you can pass a variable `mode` to that module. So if you call this module from another file you could do:

```
var config = require('/config/index.js')('staging');
```

Doing that you will be passing that word/string `'staging'` into the variable `mode` wich would basically be the same as `return config.staging;`, or return config['staging'] to be pedagogical.

The `||` chain is basically like you said. If the first is falsy it will go to the next one. So, if `mode` is `undefined`, next is `process.argv[2]` which means it will look for extra commands given when the app was called. Like `$ node index staging`. That would produce the same result as explained above.

If none of those 2 are defined, `local` will be default!
And as a safeguard: in case the config object has no property called local, or its empty it will default to `config.local`. That doesn't make much sense, unless the config object is different or can be changed outside the code example you posted. Otherwise its redudant, a repetition of the last `or`

Comment: Sergio you are great , thank you very much , this is the best explanation , i understand everything :)